# postgresql on windows server cant connect

Tags: windows, postgresql

This is with PostgreSQL 9.6.2.

At first I thought this was my problem with django or something, but it turns out it's likely not. The server is on a different machine from the client, so I need to connect to the LAN address. since that wasnt working, I tested on the server:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Test-NetConnection 192.168.1.9 -p 5432


ComputerName     : 192.168.1.9
RemoteAddress    : 192.168.1.9
RemotePort       : 5432
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet
SourceAddress    : 192.168.1.9
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

And that is in fact my postgres:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           Windows10:0            LISTENING
[postgres.exe]
```

Yet I cannot connect to the remote port even on the "server" (my desktop, as opposed to my laptop where the app is):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> C:\"Program Files"\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\psql.exe -h 192.168.1.9 -p 5432 -U dev -d postgres
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.1.9", user "dev", database "postgres", SSL off
```

But `-h localhost` **does** connect and I can see my conf files:

```
postgres=# show config_file;
                     config_file
------------------------------------------------------
 C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/postgresql.conf
(1 row)


postgres=# show hba_file;
                     hba_file
--------------------------------------------------
 C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)
```

these files don't exist after initial install, but I edited the samples and saved a copy and so it makes sense to see them showing up there.
The only changes I made to the main conf file are these four lines:

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
superuser_reserved_connections = 3  # (change requires restart)
ssl = off               # (change requires restart)
```

Everything else from the sample remains commented out.

And I added only this one line to the bottom of the pg_hba:

```
host    all             dev             192.168.1.0/24         trust
```

So that brings me to the firewall. I'd added a rule to allow connections to the port, but now I've turned completely the firewall off. Also I added PostgreSQL Server's public and private flags on the list of apps allowed to connect through the firewall. and like you can see above it is listening.

What could be the issue?

edits:

contents of the config folder:

```
PS C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\share> dir


    Diretório: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\share


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----   Saturday, 11, 3, 2017                   contrib
                          8:16 PM
d-----   Saturday, 11, 3, 2017                   extension
                          8:19 PM
d-----   Saturday, 11, 3, 2017                   locale
                          8:16 PM
d-----   Saturday, 11, 3, 2017                   timezone
                          8:19 PM
d-----   Saturday, 11, 3, 2017                   timezonesets
                          8:19 PM
d-----   Saturday, 11, 3, 2017                   tsearch_data
                          8:18 PM
-a----  Wednesday, 22, 2, 2017             75988 conversion_create.sql
                          5:35 PM
-a----  Wednesday, 22, 2, 2017            109286 information_schema.sql
                          4:29 PM
-a----    Saturday, 11, 3, 2017             4481 pg_hba.conf
                         10:26 PM
-a----  Wednesday, 22, 2, 2017              4412 pg_hba.conf.sample
                          4:29 PM
-a----  Wednesday, 22, 2, 2017              1636 pg_ident.conf.sample
                          4:29 PM
-a----  Wednesday, 22, 2, 2017               604 pg_service.conf.sample
                          4:29 PM
-a----  Wednesday, 22, 2, 2017            650392 postgres.bki
                          5:26 PM
-a----  Wednesday, 22, 2, 2017            117036 postgres.description
                          5:26 PM
-a----  Wednesday, 22, 2, 2017                50 postgres.shdescription
                          5:26 PM
-a----      Sunday, 12, 3, 2017            22258 postgresql.conf
                         12:45 AM
-a----  Wednesday, 22, 2, 2017             22201 postgresql.conf.sample
                          4:29 PM
-a----  Wednesday, 22, 2, 2017               278 psqlrc.sample
                          4:29 PM
-a----  Wednesday, 22, 2, 2017              5690 recovery.conf.sample
                          4:29 PM
-a----  Wednesday, 22, 2, 2017             25073 snowball_create.sql
                          5:35 PM
-a----  Wednesday, 22, 2, 2017             33114 sql_features.txt
                          4:29 PM
-a----  Wednesday, 22, 2, 2017             37157 system_views.sql
                          4:29 PM
```

Comment: "*these files don't exist after initial install,*" - that's impossible. If they don't exists, Postgres won't even start (and besides: it's a **really** bad idea to put the data directory into `c:\Program Files`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name well they _don't_ exist at that point, and it definitely did work for localhost connections and the initial creation of the dev user and a database. I've added the full listing of the directory to my post.

Comment: ooho! thanks for clearing that up :) Now I see. the files under share *are not the right files to edit* :) heh, ok, now it will work. Feel free to post as an answer: the fiels I needed were not under `share`, but rather under `data`

Comment: ps> could you go into more detail about the data directory? Its just a dev server on a LAN, no outside exposure here.